# Toy racetracks and topology

Tags: general-topology, plane-curves

I had a look at plane *) toy racetracks and I tried to figure out under which conditions the tracks for the two cars have equal length.

Assuming all curves consist of circular arcs $1 \ldots N$ with various different radii $r_n$ and angles $\phi_n$ it is easy to show that the condition reads

$$ \sum_n \phi_n = 0 $$

i.e. that all angles sum up to zero.

OK.

Now I would like to generalize this to arbitrary plane **) curves $X(s)$. Using the [Frenet-Serret formulas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) one finds

$$ \oint \kappa = - \oint ds \, (\dot{X}, J\ddot{X}) = 0 $$

Here $\kappa$ is the signed curvature, $J$ is a $\pi/2$ rotation, $s$ is the arc length and the dot represents differentiation w.r.t. to s.

This is nice because it indicates that this is something like a “topological invariant”. The question is **which one**? It seems to be related to the number of self-intersections ***) of the racetrack. Are there any ideas for further reading?

*) that means that only straight segments are allowed for bridges; or equivalently that bridges must not contain curves

**) that means I omitted one torsion term

***) in reality: bridges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the relevant information about the [turning number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number#Turning_number) and the [total curvature](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_curvature).